# How to add geom_point to stat_density_ridges

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges

I am able to draw density_ridge using this code. I want to add geom_point at percentile 0.50 without changing the current design. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

 ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Species, fill = factor(stat(quantile)))) +
  stat_density_ridges(
    geom = "density_ridges_gradient", calc_ecdf = TRUE,
    quantiles = 4, quantile_lines = TRUE
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
p + geom_point(data = aggregate(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris, median),
               aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species),
               color = "red",
               size = 5,
               inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

(along the way you must have called [`viridis`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/vignettes/intro-to-viridis.html) color palette it seems)

[image]

**data**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Species, fill = factor(stat(quantile)))) +
  stat_density_ridges(
    geom = "density_ridges_gradient", calc_ecdf = TRUE,
    quantiles = 4, quantile_lines = TRUE
  )
```